# Is there a way to see all ignored CSS in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I'm running after browser bugs right now. It would be very handy to see all the CSS that IE considered invalid and ignored (such as `flex: 1;`). Is this possible?

I'm looking to see the *concrete CSS rules* that were ignored on *my page*. This is not about general information about IE issues. There are hundreds, it's not possible to audit for all of them manually.

Comment: Try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And there is also a whole section on msdn about internet explorer and css: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673536(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: aren't IE dev tools enough? example in screenshot https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/04/27/0nB9.png

Comment: there are online services that can validate and offer corrections for markup and presentation errors. Please visit validator.w3.org and use those tools or if you are using Visual Studio (pro/community)... intellisence will underline unsupported style rules and markup errors. see also Why Validate: https://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html

Comment: @AdamK. this image has been lost. Can you post again?

Comment: @boot4life https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/05/09/OqRs.png - it was just a screenshot of IE - F12 - dev tools with highlighted right column, where there are visible all applied(not applied) and overriden styles. If you want maybe an output list of WHOLE HTML DOM element not applied styles, i could write a javascript bookmarklet to do that.

Comment: @AdamK. I'm not interested in styles that were merely overriden. Node, that IE10 does not support `flex: 1;` and that's the kind of problem I want to audit for. I'm looking to find bugs.